# Virtual Processing Element with Multithreading

Tags: multithreading, mips, cpu

This is a question regarding CPU architecture...

A CPU with multiple (>1) virtual processing element (VPE) with capability to do multithreading; for example, a MIPS CPU with two virtual processing element.

If these virtual processing elements share a common hardware, how can two virtual processing element work with only one pipeline? How can this be explained?

By the way, are these VPE registers have identical state?

Thanks~

Comment: http://www.imgtec.com/mips/architectures/multithreading.asp

Answer (score 2):

From the [MIPS MT documentation](http://www.imgtec.com/mips/architectures/multithreading.asp):

> However, since each VPE includes a complete copy of the processor
>   state as seen by the software system, each VPE appears as a complete
>   standalone processor to an SMP Linux operating system

and

> The use of multi-threading masks the effect of memory latency by
>   increasing processor utilization. As one thread stalls, additional
>   threads are instantly fed into the pipeline and executed, resulting in
>   a significant gain in application throughput.

For more detail you can check the *"MIPS MT Principles of Operation"* document.